# Could not DO MVC in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Getting an error when opening MVC application in Visual Studio 2010

The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Implementation.TextDocumentFactoryService' threw an exception.

I googled with this error.but didnt get tht much informative help..

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with the project, try opening VS without a project and creating a new MVC project.  If that works, then transfer your code to the new project.  If that doesn't work, then the problem may be with Visual Studio itself.  You might want to try reinstalling it.

Comment: actualy i did like u said.But the same porblem exists.Also i reinstalled the VS.But the problem still  not solved. :(